# Unable to hide or block displaying appsettings.json on the browser

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am using ASP.net Core 3.1 and trying to make appsettings.json inaccessible on the browser i.e. when I am typing `https://myapp/appsettings.json`, it's showing the contents of appsettings. I want to make it **hide or block** on the browser.

My solution explorer looks like this:

MyDeliveryWebSite

- Properties
- APIControllers
- Models
- Views
- appsettings.json
- Programs.cs
- Startup.cs

My url is: https://mydeliveryapp.cloudappp.net/appsettings.json. The output will be complete appsettings file content which I need to **hide or block** in the browser. I already tried many things. I am not sure if I am missing something out.

I am expecting the `appsettings.json` file should not be exposed publicly on the browser.

Comment: Did you just use **app.usestaticfiles()** in startup?

Comment: Does your `appsettings.json` within views?

Comment: Are you calling `appsettings.json` within your controller?  Otherthan, it shouldn't be exposed autometically. Please share more details.

Answer (score 0):

I have deployed `ASP.Net Core 3.1` sample Application and tried to access the `appsettings.json` on the browser.

I am getting the below error.

[image]

- The `appsettings.json` file has to be under `site/wwwroot` directory.

***Deployed App Structure :***

[image]

I have placed `appsettings.json` in the local `wwwroot` folder and published the app again.

Now, when I tried to access with the below URL,I am able to see the `appsettings.json` file.

***NOTE :***
Make sure your `appsettings.json` file is in the root directory in local and `site/wwwroot` directory in Azure App Service.

If the  `appsettings.json` is under local `wwwroot`, and if you deploy the app, the `appsettings.json` will be available under `site/wwwroot/ wwwroot` folder.

Which is the reason for `appsettings.json` accessible on the browser.

[image]

[image]

[image]

> I want to make it **hide or block** on the browser.

Delete the `appsettings.json` file which is under `site/wwwroot/wwwroot` directory.

***OR***

In Local, delete the `appsettings.json` file which is in `wwwroot` directory and Publish the app again.